# Не могу понять почему интервал не останавливается

Tags: javascript

Всем привет, я написал код, сделал интервал чтобы повторялась функция, но только есть проблема, мне нужно после 3 повторений остановить интервал, а почему-то это не получается, вот код:

```js
    x = 0;
    
    objects = [document.querySelector('.circleOne'),
         document.querySelector('.circleTwo'),
         document.querySelector('.circleThree')];
    
    function scaleObjects () {
     setTimeout(function() {
      objects[0].style.transform = 'scale(1.4)'; 
      objects[2].style.transform = 'scale(1)'; 
      setTimeout(function() {
       objects[1].style.transform = 'scale(1.4)'; 
       objects[0].style.transform = 'scale(1)'; 
       setTimeout(function() {
        objects[2].style.transform = 'scale(1.4)'; 
        objects[1].style.transform = 'scale(1)';
        x++;
       }, 500);
      }, 500);
     }, 500);
    }
    
    functionInterval = setInterval(scaleObjects, 1500);
    
    if (x == 3) {
     clearInterval(functionInterval);
    }
```

В чем моя проблема?

Comment: Для начала, нажмите кнопку `править` и добавьте свой код через функционал "Фрагмент кода на..." - он в редакторе вот так обозначен - `<>` (на иконке файла)

Comment: всё, я добавил.

Comment: Потому что проверка `if (x == 3)` выполняется один раз, когда еще `x===0`.

Comment: Спасибо @StepanKasyanenko

Comment: это очень злобный способ анимации